# What does hand off mean in mobile technology?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I am reading a review about iOS 8 but don't know what hand off means and also don't know what versatile means here, I found several meaning for versatile but don't know which one is the best for it here.

iOS 8 review
Love
•   Handoff
•   New keyboard is versatile
•   Health app will be big
Hate
•   Still no resizable icons
•   Not available for iPhone 4

[(Source)](http://www.t3.com/reviews/apple-ios8-review-iphone-ipad-ipod)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "handoff" here is apple's name for a specific feature, not another name for "hands-free".

Comment: @sgroves: Fair enough. I don't take much notice of Apple terminology, but you're obviously right, so I've deleted my misguided comment. But so far as I'm concerned, this effectively makes the question Off Topic...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the name of a particular technology implemented on Apple phones

Comment: @FumbleFingers but versatile is another thing i asked in this question and it is not a apple terminology.

Comment: @Riddle: It's effectively Off Topic to ask for the meanings of two unrelated words in a single question anyway. Besides which, I think the meaning of "versatile" is General Reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Here, Handoff refers to a technology Apple created and decided to call Handoff. This is evidenced by [their website](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/continuity/).

It's a reference to the term "hand off", which in football means

> to hand (a football) to a nearby teammate on a play

In a similar manner, you are taking your work from one device and accessing it via another device, i.e. handing it off from one to the other.

**2:** Regarding the keyboard being "versatile", it most likely refers to the fact that you can now write things to the keyboard in more than one way. Instead of just typing on it, the author mentions you can now use a microphone as well as use word suggestions through "QuickType". Thus, the keyboard is versatile:

> able to adapt or be adapted to many different functions or activities

Comment: in the source given in the question there is a sentence "And, is it just me, or is even the title lettering for Doctor Who flatter, too?" do you know what it means?

Comment: I believe he's trying to make an unrelated joke by saying the title of the TV show "Doctor Who" has changed over the years. He's suggesting that Apple has such huge influence that by changing the words and icons to be flatter (appearing less 3-D) that it not only affects other smartphone companies (Samsung & LG) but TV studios. I don't think it's meant to be taken seriously, however.

Answer (score 2):

In mobile technology [handoff](http://www.phonearena.com/htmls/terms.php?define=Handoff) refers to the transfer of data or calls of a mobile phone from one base station to another:

> - The process of transferring an ongoing mobile phone call or data session from one base station to a geographically adjacent base station as the user is in motion. In a properly functioning network, handoff occurs smoothly, without gaps in communications and it is usually not noticed by the cellular user.

Regarding Apple new devise it refers to the automatic transfer of data and advanced interaction among  devices of the same brand.

The keyboard is versatile in the sense that it has been developed  to make writing easier and quicker interacting with the user.  It is also called *[intelligent keyboard](http://recode.net/2014/09/16/new-iphone-6-keyboard/).*

Comment: in the source given in the question there is a sentence "And, is it just me, or is even the title lettering for Doctor Who flatter, too?" do you know what it means?